# Функция работает только при обновлении страницы

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, я сделал расширение для хрома, чтобы удалять лишний дочерний блок контента **ВК** во вкладке "Музыка".

Но проблема в том, что он удаляется только при обновлении страницы

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Savage Mode",
    "description": "I'm in Savage Mode",
    "version": "1.0",
    "author": "twenty one savage",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Savage Mode",
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
"content_scripts": [
{
    "matches": [
    "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js" :["jquery.js", "content.js"]
}

]   
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var element = document.querySelector('.CatalogBlock--divided');
element.parentElement.removeChild(element);
```

Хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы всё работало при переходе в нужный раздел

Comment: чтобы всё работало при переходе в нужный раздел, нужно вызвать этот код при переходе в нужный раздел

Comment: как это сделать

Comment: не проще правилами AdBlock скрыть?

Comment: adblock удаляет сразу же все элементы с этим классом, а мне нужно удалить отдельный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому-что это не просто страница, а приложение. И внедрить в нее скрипт с одноразовым удалением - не выйдет. Необходимо отслеживать изменения на странице.

В простом варианте это делается с помощью [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe)

Прослеживать изменения стоит на самом ближайшем родительском блоке, который никогда не удаляется.

```js
// Найти самый ближайший родительский блок который никогда не удаляется
const root = document.querySelector('.CatalogBlock--divided')
  // У нас это будет class="main"
  .parentElement

// Простейшая функция поиска при обновлении родительского элемента
function update () {
  const bad = root.querySelector('.CatalogBlock--divided')
  if (!bad) return
  bad.remove()
  console.log('Удалили блок')
}

// Запустить на нем отслеживание дочерних элементов
new MutationObserver(update)
  .observe(root, { childList: true })

// +++ ВСЕ ЧТО НИЖЕ ЭТО ДЛЯ ТЕСТА +++

// Сперва скопируем
const bad = document.querySelector('.CatalogBlock--divided').cloneNode(true)

// Добавляем его каждые 2 сек - как буд-то это делает приложение сайта
setInterval(() => {
  if (root.querySelector('.CatalogBlock--divided')) return
  root.appendChild(bad.cloneNode(true))
  console.log('Добавили блок')
}, 2000)

// Удаляем впервые
setTimeout(update, 1000)
```

```css
.main {
  padding: 10px;

}

.CatalogBlock--divided {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.other {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #8bc34a;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="other">Good</div>
  <div class="CatalogBlock--divided">Bad</div>
</div>
```

Этот вариант плох тем, что если родительский(фиксированный) блок окажется очень далеко, например это body, возрастет нагрузка на `MutationObserver`, но работать будет. Если же примерно как в данном примере - это фактически идеальный вариант.

Возможно проще внедрить стили с `display: none` для этого класса.

Comment: проблема такая, что такой код удаляет все 3 блока .CatalogBlock--divided. Мне нужно чтобы удалился только первый из трёх

Comment: @SaintLaurentDon, не проще через стили ```.CatalogBlock--divided:first-child { display: none;```?

Comment: @SaintLaurentDon Это не проблема, а недоработка скрипта с поиском блока. Я не пользуюсь ВК и не могу даже видеть как выглядит страница. Я лишь показал скелет скрипта в который следует дописать свое правило поиска этого конкретного блока. Если туда можно влезть без аккаунта, давай ссылку.

Comment: @SaintLaurentDon А вон уже  OliverPatterson подсказал правильный селектор

Comment: @AlexanderLonberd но я не могу редактировать стили и html страницы

Comment: @SaintLaurentDon Если не сможешь редактировать css, и там точно всегда три блока, можно взять все три блока массивом `querySelectorsAll('.CatalogBlock--divided')` проверить три ли их там на текущий момент обновления и удалить первый в списке. Но мне кажется что его все-таки можно идентифицировать по каким либо признакам - жаль я не могу посмотреть.

Comment: @SaintLaurentDon У всех разделов есть заголовки, причем у каждого разный класс, именно по ним можно идентифицировать блок.
У первого раздела селектор заголовка будет выглядеть так `querySelector('.CatalogBlock--divided h2.CatalogRecentAudiosHeader')`.
Как выше я писал берешь все блока `querySelectorsAll('.CatalogBlock--divided')` и проверяешь каждый есть ли в нем этот заголовок.
Там же все блоки разные, можно 100500 способов идентификации придумать.

Comment: @SaintLaurentDon Если кратко `querySelectorsAll('.CatalogBlock--divided').map((v)=>v.querySelector('h2.CatalogRecentAudiosHeader'))` и проверяешь осталось ли что в массиве.

Comment: @SaintLaurentDon Ой, только не `map`, а `filter` - ошибся :(